# How to improve English skill for IT

Tags: writing, listening

I am a graduate program in Vietnam, English is a second language.

I have some feeling and the servey about the current work.

Advantage: using the computer more than 8 hours per day, and the information sources used mostly documents written in English.

Weaknesses: Poor communication environment and practice, limiting the skills of listening, speaking and writing.

How now I can combine programming with learning English for Effective?
Sincere thanks!

Comment: You mention being in IT.  Assuming you mean software development, then I would suggest finding an Open-Source project that you find interesting, and start hanging around their open discussion forums.  This will help improve your English and IT skills.

Comment: My advice would be to start with books for children, both print and recorded versions, and listen to a native speaker reading the book ("on tape") while you follow along with the book. After some time,  as your vocabulary and your "ear" improve, you can "graduate" to books for older children, then for teenagers, and then...

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering that programming has its own array of syntax and language, I think you'd be hard-pressed to find a way to teach yourself programming and English at the same time. Almost all programming languages do use English keywords, but obviously the grammar, vocabulary, and cultural context isn't there.

The best way to make sure you learn a language is to practice with someone. You should not only read IT forums, but make it a habit to post there, even if your English is terrible. Always observe native English speaking members of the forum, and try to start following their conventions (but only if you're sure that you aren't picking up a bad habit). This is only a way to practice. You should also try to learn from a textbook, or ideally, a class. If you ever get the opportunity, try to join a voice chat with someone and speak to them. That way, you'll learn how to pronounce the words, not just write them. I've heard a story about a foreign student who came to an American university after only studying English from a textbook. He pronounced "science" like "skunk" with an "i" instead of a "u." If you have any questions that your textbook can't answer and you can't figure out just by observing native English speakers, then you can ask them here.

I think the fastest way to pick up a language is by speaking with someone (with voice, not text) in real time. Obviously this isn't easy to do on a regular basis, but you should try to do it whenever you can. This will teach you how to speak in a normal conversation quickly, but it won't get you to be completely fluent in the language. You still need to study vocabulary and grammar to be able to express yourself fully.